# Recovering from: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server

Tags: c#, exception

I have an windows forms application that does a few automation tasks. I would like the app to be able to recover from network errors and carry on doing its tasks when the connection becomes available again.

While the app is doing its tasks I unplug the network cable. I then get the error in the question title. Problem is I don't know what kind of exception that is? Only place I can handle it it seems is with a ThreadExceptionEventHandler, but thats no use since I'm completely out of the flow of tasks now. I need to be able to handle the error with a catch block.

```
//Small example

while(running == true)
{
    try {
      dotask1(); //network related tasks
      dotask2(); //db tasks
      dotask3(); //bla bla
      dotask4(); //wishy washy
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Want this to happen, but it never does??
        //Sleep here a bit (were in a Backgroundworker here) and continue
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeoutSleepInterval"]));

        continue;  //Keep doing tasks 1,2,3,4
        //Not even a catch all catches this kind of exception?!?!?
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `running = true` needs to be `running == true`.

Comment: Thanks, typo when I created the mock example above. Its correct in the actual code.